# Unity開発OSX向けファイル選択ダイアログが開かない

Tags: macos, unity2d

Unityで開発を行っております。
Unityのバージョンを2018.4.22f1から2020.3.1f1にバージョンアップしました。

その後、OSX用アプリを出力したのですが、
そこで今まで使用していたファイル選択ダイアログが開かないことがわかりました。

// UnityStandaloneFileBrowser
https://github.com/gkngkc/UnityStandaloneFileBrowser

を使用していたのですが、こちら32Bitシステム向けの為、
現在の64Bitシステム向けのアプリでは動かないためと分かりましたが、
これに代わるファイル選択システムは何かご存じでしょうか。

他64Bitシステムのツールを使用しているため、Unityのダウングレードは考えておりません。

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: この Issue で紹介されているものがあるようですが。[How to use the MacOS StandaloneFileBrowser file in subfolder for MacOS build? #83](https://github.com/gkngkc/UnityStandaloneFileBrowser/issues/83) -> [The Story About .NET Cross Platform UI Frameworks](https://blog.lextudio.com/the-story-about-net-cross-platform-ui-frameworks-dd4a9433d0ea)

Comment: 64bit 対応までされているかは分かりませんが、参照されているリポジトリから Fork したリポジトリで Unity 2020.3 への対応を行っているものがあるようです。 https://github.com/shutosg/UnityStandaloneFileBrowser/commits/master